# How to change the list element inplace in a class method

Tags: python, sudoku, in-place

[Sudoku Solver](https://leetcode.com/problems/sudoku-solver/)

Here I want to solve the given sudoku inplace

```
class Solution:
def solveSudoku(self, board: List[List[str]]) -> None:
    """
    Do not return anything, modify board in-place instead.
    """
    def is_correct(row, col, num):
        #column
        for c in range(9):
            if board[row][c] == num:
                return False

        #row
        for r in range(9):
            if board[r][col] == num:
                return False

        #square
        x = row//3 * 3
        y = col//3 * 3
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                if board[x+i][y+j] == num:
                    return False
        return True

    def find_next():
        
        for i in range(9):
            for j in range(9):
                if board[i][j] == '.':
                    return i, j
        return None, None

    def solve():
        row, col = find_next()

        if row == None:
            print(board)
            return True
    

        for i in range(1, 10):
            if is_correct(row, col, str(i)):
                board[row][col] = str(i)

                solve()

            board[row][col] = '.'
    
    solve()
```

The `print` function in the `solve` function returns the solved sudoku board but it is not changing it inplace. How can I change the function so that I changes the board inplace?

Comment: You want the text to change on the terminal without redrawing the board?

Comment: I assume that you're talking about output to the terminal and not outputting an full board and having it scroll the screen to replace the prior board, but rather have the few characters that need to change seem to just change with no redrawing or scrolling of the rest of the board.  Is that right.  If so, then the only way I know to do stuff like that is with Curses.  Check out https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html.

Comment: @Mike67 I am trying to solve the problem in the mentioned link. But the "board" which is being passed as a parameter is not changing globally but only changing in the `solve` function locally. But i want to change it globally. Please refer the link for further details

Comment: @Steve I am trying to solve the problem mentioned link and i got the above problem of the parameter "board" not changing globally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the solution is found, return `True` up the call stack.

Try this code:

```
board = [
["5","3",".",".","7",".",".",".","."],
["6",".",".","1","9","5",".",".","."],
[".","9","8",".",".",".",".","6","."],
["8",".",".",".","6",".",".",".","3"],
["4",".",".","8",".","3",".",".","1"],
["7",".",".",".","2",".",".",".","6"],
[".","6",".",".",".",".","2","8","."],
[".",".",".","4","1","9",".",".","5"],
[".",".",".",".","8",".",".","7","9"]]

class Solution:
   def solveSudoku(self, board) -> None:
     """
     Do not return anything, modify board in-place instead.
     """
     solve()
    
def is_correct(row, col, num):
    #column
    for c in range(9):
        if board[row][c] == num:
            return False

    #row
    for r in range(9):
        if board[r][col] == num:
            return False

    #square
    x = row//3 * 3
    y = col//3 * 3
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if board[x+i][y+j] == num:
                return False
    return True

def find_next():
    
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            if board[i][j] == '.':
                return i, j
    return None, None

def solve():
    #print(id(board))
    row, col = find_next()

    if row == None:
        #print(board)
        return True


    for i in range(1, 10):
        if is_correct(row, col, str(i)):
            board[row][col] = str(i)

            if solve(): return True  # solution found
            board[row][col] = '.'  # no solution yet

Solution().solveSudoku(board)

print(board)  # global board
```

Output

```
[['5', '3', '4', '6', '7', '8', '9', '1', '2'], 
 ['6', '7', '2', '1', '9', '5', '3', '4', '8'], 
 ['1', '9', '8', '3', '4', '2', '5', '6', '7'], 
 ['8', '5', '9', '7', '6', '1', '4', '2', '3'], 
 ['4', '2', '6', '8', '5', '3', '7', '9', '1'], 
 ['7', '1', '3', '9', '2', '4', '8', '5', '6'], 
 ['9', '6', '1', '5', '3', '7', '2', '8', '4'], 
 ['2', '8', '7', '4', '1', '9', '6', '3', '5'], 
 ['3', '4', '5', '2', '8', '6', '1', '7', '9']]
```